# Cannot understand some parts of proof for R be a countable union of closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, baire-category

Im reading chapter9 Category, Real Analysis, Carothers, 1ed, talking about discontinuous functions of metric space. Here is a proof for a theorem that R be a countable union of closed sets,:
[image]

Baire's theorem involved is,:
[image]

1. What is the "entire open interval"?
2. Is "$E_n$ contains an interval" the same as interior of $E_n$ is not empty?
3. if $E_n$ has empty interior, that means complement of $G_n$ has empty interior, then equivalently, this will imply that $G_n$ is dense and make a contradiction here, is that right?
4. What im still confusing about is how can we suppose if $\mathbb{R}$ = a countable union of closed sets?

Comment: If the interval is $(a,b)$, the entire open interval is $(a,b)$. (As opposed to "only part of the open interval".)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: But where is (a,b)? you mean R is (-infinity, +infinity), an open interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to part 4 of your question, we have
$$
\mathbb R = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb Z} [-n, n]
$$
which is a countable union of closed sets.

Comment: Ohhh, that's right. Thank u^_^

Comment: BTW, I can still use open (-n, n) instead of the closed one, is that right?

Comment: I mean the union of open ones will still be equal to R.

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: @bof: cosets is what?